# #1064 - MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' error?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

i have created a stored procedure in order to insert data into database, as i am new to stored procedure i am not getting the exact solution for this problem, the following is my query :

```
create PROCEDURE retrieveSiteDetails
(in longitude varchar(50),in latitude varchar(50),in email_id varchar(60),in file_id varchar(10),
 in unique_site_id varchar(25),in description varchar(150),in site varchar(30),in batch varchar(20),
 in group_is varchar(85),in enumeration varchar(20),in created_at datetime,in modified_at datetime)
 BEGIN
 insert into geodata (longitude,latitude,email_id,file_id, unique_site_id,description,site,batch,
  group_is,enumeration,created_at,modified_at) values (in_longitude,in_latitude,in_email_id,
in_file_id,in_unique_site_id,in_description,in_site,in_batch,in_group_is,in_enumeration,
in_created_at,in_modified_at);
 END
```

please help me to solve this query problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this format for creating procedures from mysql client.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE DBNAME$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS <Your Procedure_name>$$

CREATE PROCEDURE <Your Procedure_name>( <Parameter1>,<Parameter2>......<Parametern>)
BEGIN

<Your statements>;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i have already use semicolon at the end of insert query and before END word

Comment: I have edited the format for creating procedure from mysql client.